# How can i use modulus the loop through integers -10 to 10?

Tags: processing, modulus

I understand that i can use modulus to loop through positive numbers e.g 0 to 10 would look something like this:

```
i++;
i %= 10;
```

But how can i make it so instead of starting back at 0 it starts at -10?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use modulus.

```
i++;
if (i >= 10) i = -10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this be the solution?

```
i = i%20 - 10;
```